# When does $F(x,y) = 0$ imply an implicit function?

Tags: calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Consider $F: D \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. If I call

$$ F(x,y) = 0$$

an implicit equation, then presumably, because I'm calling this an implicit equation, I'm implying there exists at least one function $g(x)$ over some interval $I$ which satisfies $F(x,g(x)) = 0$.

Let's consider

$$ x^2 + y^2 + 1 = 0 \tag{1}$$
This equation does not define an implicit function $y  = g(x)$. Wikipedia would still call $(1)$ an implicit equation. I'd like to reserve the word for cases  which actually do imply an implicit function. Anyways, why doesn't the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) work on equation $(1)$? The wikipedia article is a little abstract and general for me, so I looked up an implicit function theorem in 2 variables.

The domain of $F$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$. The partial derivatives
$$ F_x = 2x \\
F_y = 2y$$
exist and are continuous. $F_y = 0 $ only when $y = 0$. So it seems like an implicit function should exist according to the theorem (possibly on each side of $y = 0$ in the plane), even though we know one doesn't?

Why does

$$x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$$

satisfy the conditions of the theorem but $(1)$ doesn't? I must be missing something simple here

Comment: As an aside, the generalization of this theorem to $\mathbf{R}^n$ "looks like" the two-variable case exactly. The only difference is that there are matrices of derivatives rather than single derivatives. But like you said, it's a little hard to parse when you first see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply the implicit function theorem, you **have to fix** a point $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R^2}$, such that $f(a, b) = 0$. But there is no such point **in $\mathbb{R}^2$**: Assume the validity of (1) for some $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^2$. $(1) \implies x^2 + y^2 = -1$. But if both $x$ and $y$ are in $\mathbb{R}$, their squares are nonnegative and likewise the sum of their squares ($x^2 + y^2$) too. Contradiction.

(Probably, there are such points in $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \mathbb{R}^2$, but these are not relevant.)

$x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$ defines the unit circle in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Especially, there are points fulfilling $f(a, b) = 0$ (e. g. $a = 0$, $b = 1$) and with an invertible Jacobian matrix at this point (c. f. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#The_circle_example))

Comment: Thank you for this very nice answer!

Comment: You are welcome :-)